# Pass parameter to an executable file running in windows command prompt

Tags: vbscript, cmd, exe

How can I pass parameters to an executable file (created using a vbscript and imported using vbsedit to become executable) in command prompt?

```
start C:\scripts\myexecutablefile.exe myparameter
```

Comment: `start "" "C:\scripts\myexecutablefile.exe" myparameter` - according to [relevant resources](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Comment: This runs the exe file, but seems that the executable file does not receive the parameter passed. Here's a piece of code I used in vbscript (before compiling to exe) to get parameters:
 Set Args = WScript.Arguments
 propertyFile = Args(0)

Comment: What about your prime _vbscript (before compiling to exe)_? Does it work? `wscript.echo "Args.Count =", Args.Count` could help... Not much more to say, as I don't know `vbsedit`...

Comment: the vbscript works well when ran using cscript in the command line. cscript c:\scripts\myexecutablefile.exe myparameter. Thank you